# About sequences in the unit bal converging to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $c_0$ be all sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ that converge to zero.
Prove that for every $x \in B_{c_0} := \{x \in c_0 : ||x||_\infty = 1\}$, there exist $x_1, x_2 \in B_{c_0},x = \frac{1}{2}(x_1 + x_2)$, while $x_1 \neq x_2$.

I have already: for every $x_1, x_2$ as given we have $||\frac{1}{2}(x_1 + x_2)||_\infty = 1$ and $\frac{1}{2}(x_1 + x_2)$ converges to zero, because $c_0$ is closed in $\ell^\infty$.
I think that for every $x$ there is a $y$ with $y = e^{i\pi a}x$, a rotation of the sequence. Is that true? If so I think I can construct a sequence $z$ with for all $i\geq1$: $|z_i| = |x_i|$ and Arg$(z_i)$ is the angle of rotation between $x$ and $y$. Then $\frac{1}{2}(y + z) = x$. Is that right?

Comment: Is there enough room for dancing in the unit "bal"  ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I am not sure what you mean with dancing?

Comment: For sure, don't lok for a mathematical meaning: I wouln't have made this little joke if you had added written "ball" with a double "l"...

Comment: Hahaha oh well, not a native speaker here, as you may have figured by now...

Comment: Neither me ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint :* since $x$ goes to zero, one of its terms has absolute value stricly less than $1$ and is therefore the mean average of two different numbers with absolute value less than or equal to 1.

Comment: wow okay so the requested sequences exist and are in $c_0$ because for every term $x_n \in x$ the maximum norm of the found numbers is $2x_n$, which also converges to zero. Thank you!